# Why did Danny Rand (Iron Fist) pose as the Daredevil?

Tags: comics, marvel, daredevil

We all know that Matt Murdock is the real Daredevil. At some point Danny Rand dressed up as Daredevil and tried to take on his role.

Why did Danny Rand (Iron Fist) pose as the Daredevil, and how did he do it?

Comment: Wait? Matt Murdock is Daredevil? Spoilers, dangit!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### It was part of a plan to convince people that Matt Murdock was not Daredevil. Since Daredevil has no signature powers, it was relatively easy for Daniel Rand (who is secretly Iron Fist, master martial artist) to take on the role. There are a number of story arcs going on including the Civil War arc.  During this time Murdock is in witness protection, in prison, trying to avoid being killed by all of the criminals he has helped put behind bars.

> The impact of his exposure as Daredevil continued to be used as a plot point by both Bendis and writer Ed Brubaker and artist Michael Lark, who became the new creative team with Daredevil vol. 2, #82 (Feb. 2006), no longer under the Marvel Knights imprint.
>
> Brubaker's first story arc had a new character masquerading as Daredevil in Hell's Kitchen. Murdock later discovered the ersatz Daredevil is his friend Danny Rand, the superhero, Iron Fist.
>
> **Brubaker said:** "Yes, I'm relieved, but at the same time, it was always the plan to reveal it this issue, and it was never meant to be as big a deal as it ended up being. It was just one part of a much larger story, one that the next arc follows up on. This whole 'who's the other DD' mystery that cropped up the last few weeks and ran around the Internet was unplanned, and I thought it was really amusing to watch, though a little nerve-wracking at the same time. I'm just glad it wasn't the only secret we were sitting on."

Comment: Is this from the wiki?